# I wanted to use object a class twice but it's not happening

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl

basic.py

```
from OpenGL.GL import*
from OpenGL.GLU import*
from OpenGL.GLUT import*
import sys

class Draw:
   # def draw_func(self):
   #     pass

    def draw(self):
        glutInit(sys.argv)
        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGB)
        glutInitWindowSize(1000,1000)
        glutInitWindowPosition(50,50)
        glutCreateWindow(b'Cycle')
        glutDisplayFunc(self.draw_func)
        glClearColor(0,0,0,1)
        gluOrtho2D(-500,500,-500,100)
        glutMainLoop()
```

cycle.py

```
class Circle(Draw):
   def __init__(self,xv,yv):
      self.xv=xv
      self.yv= yv

   def draw_circle(self):
      glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
      glColor3f(1, 0, 0)
      glPointSize(3)
    for t in arange(self.xv, self.yv, 0.001):
        x = 50 * sin(t)
        y = 50 * cos(t)
        glBegin(GL_POINTS)
        glVertex2f(x, y)
        glEnd()
        glFlush()

   def draw_func(self):
      self.draw_circle()

cycle = Circle(100,200)
cycle.draw()
cycle = Circle(220,300)
cycle.draw()
```

Here I am using pyOpenGl to learn graphics and  I wanted to use the Circle object twice to draw 2 circle but it draws only one . I don't know where I am lacking my knowledge. Also please suggest me any tutorials to learn pyOpenGl I didn't find the good one.

Answer (score 1):

The instruction

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
```

clears the complete color plane of the frambuffer. This means you clear the frambuffer before you draw the 2nd circle.

Remove `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)` from the `draw` method and do it at the begin of the drawing instructions. Further `glFlush` should be done after the drawing instructions.

See [`glClear`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glClear.xhtml):

> `glClear` sets the bitplane area of the window to values previously selected by `glClearColor`.

Your architecture is not proper. You should not derive `Circle` from `Draw`, but `Draw` should use `Circle`. 
This means you have to create a `class Draw` which does the initializations and handles the main loop. The other separated `class Circle` draws a single circle:

```
class Circle:
    def __init__(self,xv,yv):
        self.xv=xv
        self.yv= yv

    def draw(self):
        glColor3f(1, 0, 0)
        glPointSize(3)
        for t in arange(self.xv, self.yv, 0.001):
        x = 50 * sin(t)
        y = 50 * cos(t)
        glBegin(GL_POINTS)
        glVertex2f(x, y)
        glEnd()
```

```
class Draw:
    def __init__(self,cx,cy):
        self.cx = cx
        self.cy = cy

    def draw(self):
        glutInit(sys.argv)
        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGB)
        glutInitWindowSize(self.cx,self.cy)
        glutInitWindowPosition(50,50)
        glutCreateWindow(b'Cycle')
        glutDisplayFunc(self.draw_loop)
        glClearColor(0,0,0,1)
        gluOrtho2D(-self.cx/2,self.cx/2,-self.cy/2,self.cy/2)
        glutMainLoop()

    def draw_loop(self):
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT) 

        cycle = Circle(100,200)
        cycle.draw()
        cycle = Circle(220,300)
        cycle.draw()

        glFlush()
        glutPostRedisplay()
```

```
wnd = Draw(1000,1000)
wnd.draw()
```

Comment: it gave error in the first line
 'glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
cycle = Circle(100,200)
cycle.draw()
cycle = Circle(220,300)
cycle.draw()'

Comment: @BishwaKarki What error did you get? The code did not change. Only the order of the instructions has changed. - See the changes to the answer.

Comment: OpenGL.error.GLError: GLError(
 err = 1282,
 description = b'invalid operation',
 baseOperation = glClear,
 cArguments = (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT,)
)
 This is the error produce

Comment: @BishwaKarki See the changes to the answer